# Accessing a compiled Python module's AST or symbol table

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, abstract-syntax-tree, pyc

**Background:**

I have a pure-Python module that defines a few sentinels:

```
foo = object()

# for backwards compatibility
bar = foo
```

I'd like to get a mapping between the `object` instances and the variable names. To do that, I import the module and loop over the variables:

```
signals = {}

for name, obj in vars(module).items():
    if type(obj) == object:
        signals[obj] = name
```

**Problem**:

The order of the variables isn't preserved, so `bar` ends up wrongly replacing `foo` in the mapping.

How do I get only the variables defined like `foo = object()` and not `bar = foo`?

**Somewhat working solutions**:

I know it can be done with the `ast` module, but my module may not have a corresponding `.py` file, so `inspect.getsource(module)` just returns the contents of the `pyc` file. `ast.parse()` won't parse that and I don't really want to add a new dependency.

It can also be done with the `symtable` module via the `Symbol.is_referenced()` method, but that suffers from the same problem as the `ast` approach.

Is there an elegant way of doing this without hard-coding the mapping?